# How to create "products filter" efficiently in Node.js and Angular?

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, mongodb

I'm creating an angular application (computer online store) with a node/express backened. I have a products page to display all the products in my DB. A product has this model (typescript):

```
interface Product {
  name: string
  properties: {name: string, value: string | number}[]
}
```

I have a section within the page where you can filter products by properties. for instance a user can filter all the CPUs that have 4 cores or 8 cores. right now this is implemented like this:

In the angular application i query *ALL THE PRODUCTS* of the requested category,
loop through all of them, collect their properties and all the possible values and filter like this...

```
const products = [
{
  name: 'intel cpu 1',
  properties: [
    {name: 'cores', value: 8},
    {name: 'clock speed', value: 2.6}
  ]
},
{
  name: 'intel cpu 2',
  properties: [
    {name: 'cores', value: 4},
    {name: 'clock speed', value: 1.2}
  ]
}
]

collectPropertiesFromProducts(products)

// RESULT: 
[
  {property: 'cores', possibleValues: [4,8]},
  {property: 'clock speed', possibleValues: [1.2,2.6]}
]
```

For now it works great, i can filter products easily by the result and it is all dynamic (i can just add a property to a product and thats it).

The problem is that it scales *VERY BADLY*, because:

- I have to query all of the products to know their properties
- The more products/properties = more CPU time = blocks main thread

My question is how can i do better? i have a node server so moving all the logic to there its pretty useless, i could also just move the "property collecting" function to a worker thread but again, ill have to query all the products...

Comment: Why is moving all the logic to the backend "pretty useless"? I'd argue it is the only valid solution. Depending on how your DB is structured, you may find it useful to index it on the various filterable properties.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of dealing with this in the client or in the service itself, you can let mongodb do the calculations for you. E.g. you could write the following aggregation:

```
db.getCollection('products').aggregate([{
            $unwind: "$properties"
        },
        {
            $project: {
                name: "$properties.name",
                total: {
                    $add: ["$properties.value", ]
                }
            }
        }, {
            $group: {
                _id: "$name",
                possibleValues: {
                    $addToSet: "$total"
                }
            }
        }

    ])
```

You could then expose this query through a custom endpoint (e.g. `GET /product-properties`) on your node-server and consume the response on the client.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider doing multiple requests to the backend:

**First**:
getQueryParams, a new endpoint which returns your RESULT

**Second**:
A none filtered request to receive the initial set of products

**Third**:
When select a filter (based on first request) you do a new request with the selected filter